# Пример перевода кода с C# на C++

Tags: c#, c++, перевод

У меня есть код на С# (esemples.cs). Я пытаюсь его перевести на С++ и у меня появилось пара вопросов. Я попробую изложить сначала сам код, потом что смог "навертеть", а после детали которые я хотел бы понять и "прояснить".

Вот код **esemples.cs** :

```
// Описание битого пикселя и набора его соседей с весовыми коэффициентами
public struct BadPixel
{
    public int Index; // Теперь это первый два элемента массивы - X и Y
    public InterpolationPixel[] InterpolationPixels; // Теперь это блоки по 3 значения, начиная с 3-го элемента массива (xi, yi, wi)
}


// Описание сосднего пикселя с битым и его весового коэффициента
public struct InterpolationPixel
{
    public int Index; // Теперь это xi и yi
    public float Weight; // Теперь это wi
}


// Метод создания структуры коррекции битвых пикселей изображения
public DetectorCalibration.InterpolationPixel[] FindBadPixelInterpolations(int index, int imageWidth, int imageHeight, ISet<int> badPixelSet) {
    var interpolationPixels = new List<DetectorCalibration.InterpolationPixel>();
    var x = index % imageWidth;
    var y = index / imageWidth;

    // Крест для поиска усреднения лево-право-верх-низ
    var leftRight = new InterpolationLine(badPixelSet, index, x, imageWidth - x - 1, 1);
    var topBottom = new InterpolationLine(badPixelSet, index, y, imageHeight - y - 1, imageWidth);

    if (!AddInterpolationLines(interpolationPixels, leftRight, topBottom)) {
        // Диагональный крест для усреднения
        var diag1 = new InterpolationLine(badPixelSet, index, Math.Min(x, y), Math.Min(imageWidth - x - 1, imageHeight - y - 1), imageWidth + 1);
        var diag2 = new InterpolationLine(badPixelSet, index, Math.Min(imageWidth - x - 1, y), Math.Min(x, imageHeight - y - 1), imageWidth - 1);

        if (!AddInterpolationLines(interpolationPixels, diag1, diag2)) {
            //  Берем хоть какие-то точки из креста лево-право-верх-низ
            var weight = 1f / (
                             (leftRight.Has1 ? 1f : 0f) +
                             (leftRight.Has2 ? 1f : 0f) +
                             (topBottom.Has1 ? 1f : 0f) +
                             (topBottom.Has2 ? 1f : 0f));
            if (leftRight.Has1)
                interpolationPixels.Add(new DetectorCalibration.InterpolationPixel {Index = leftRight.PixelIndex1, Weight = weight});
            if (leftRight.Has2)
                interpolationPixels.Add(new DetectorCalibration.InterpolationPixel {Index = leftRight.PixelIndex2, Weight = weight});
            if (topBottom.Has1)
                interpolationPixels.Add(new DetectorCalibration.InterpolationPixel {Index = topBottom.PixelIndex1, Weight = weight});
            if (topBottom.Has2)
                interpolationPixels.Add(new DetectorCalibration.InterpolationPixel 
                {Index = topBottom.PixelIndex2, 
                Weight = weight});
        }
    }

    return interpolationPixels.ToArray();
}


// Внутренняя структура для алгоритма, описывающая одну линию интерполяции
private class InterpolationLine
{
    public readonly float Distance1 = float.PositiveInfinity;
    public readonly int PixelIndex1;
    public readonly float Distance2 = float.PositiveInfinity;
    public readonly int PixelIndex2;

    public InterpolationLine(ISet<int> badPixelIndexes, int badPixelIndex, int maxDistance1, int maxDistance2, int step) {
        maxDistance1 = Math.Min(MAX_DISTANCE, maxDistance1);
        maxDistance2 = Math.Min(MAX_DISTANCE, maxDistance2);

        var index = badPixelIndex;
        for (var distance = 1; distance <= maxDistance1; distance++) {
            index -= step;
            if (!badPixelIndexes.Contains(index)) {
                PixelIndex1 = index;
                Distance1 = distance;
                break;
            }
        }

        index = badPixelIndex;
        for (var distance = 1; distance <= maxDistance2; distance++) {
            index += step;
            if (!badPixelIndexes.Contains(index)) {
                PixelIndex2 = index;
                Distance2 = distance;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool Has1 =>
        MMath.IsFinite(Distance1);

    public bool Has2 =>
        MMath.IsFinite(Distance2);

    public bool IsComplete =>
        Has1 && Has2;

    public float MaxDistance =>
        Math.Max(Distance1, Distance2);

    public float Weight1 =>
        1f / (1f + Distance1 / Distance2);

    public float Weight2 =>
        1f / (1f + Distance2 / Distance1);
}


// Внутренний метод 
private bool AddInterpolationLines(ICollection<DetectorCalibration.InterpolationPixel> interpolationPixels, InterpolationLine a, InterpolationLine b) {
    if (a.IsComplete && b.IsComplete && Math.Abs(a.MaxDistance - b.MaxDistance) < DISTANCE_DIFFERENCE_THRESHOLD) {
        // Усреднение крестом
        interpolationPixels.Add(new DetectorCalibration.InterpolationPixel {Index = a.PixelIndex1, Weight = 0.5f * a.Weight1});
        interpolationPixels.Add(new DetectorCalibration.InterpolationPixel {Index = a.PixelIndex2, Weight = 0.5f * a.Weight2});
        interpolationPixels.Add(new DetectorCalibration.InterpolationPixel {Index = b.PixelIndex1, Weight = 0.5f * b.Weight1});
        interpolationPixels.Add(new DetectorCalibration.InterpolationPixel {Index = b.PixelIndex2, Weight = 0.5f * b.Weight2});
    }
    else if (a.IsComplete && (!b.IsComplete || a.MaxDistance < b.MaxDistance)) {
        // Усреднение по одному направлению
        interpolationPixels.Add(new DetectorCalibration.InterpolationPixel {Index = a.PixelIndex1, Weight = a.Weight1});
        interpolationPixels.Add(new DetectorCalibration.InterpolationPixel {Index = a.PixelIndex2, Weight = a.Weight2});
    }
    else if (b.IsComplete && (!a.IsComplete || b.MaxDistance < a.MaxDistance)) {
        // Усреднение по другому направлению
        interpolationPixels.Add(new DetectorCalibration.InterpolationPixel {Index = b.PixelIndex1, Weight = b.Weight1});
        interpolationPixels.Add(new DetectorCalibration.InterpolationPixel {Index = b.PixelIndex2, Weight = b.Weight2});
    }

    return interpolationPixels.Count > 0;
}
```

Вот что мне удалось, "намахать".

Вот С++ заголовочный (esemples.h):

```
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>

// Описание битого пикселя и набора его соседей с весовыми коэффициентами
class BadPixel
{
public:
    int Index = 0; // Теперь это первый два элемента массивы - X и Y
    std::vector<InterpolationPixel> InterpolationPixels; // Теперь это блоки по 3 значения, начиная с 3-го элемента массива (xi, yi, wi)
};


// Описание сосднего пикселя с битым и его весового коэффициента
class InterpolationPixel
{
public:
    int Index = 0; // Теперь это xi и yi
    float Weight = 0; // Теперь это wi
};

// Внутренняя структура для алгоритма, описывающая одну линию интерполяции
class InterpolationLine
{
public:
    const float Distance1 = std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity();
    const int PixelIndex1;
    const float Distance2 = std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity();
    const int PixelIndex2;

    InterpolationLine(ISet<int> *badPixelIndexes, int badPixelIndex, int maxDistance1, int maxDistance2, int step);

    bool getHas1() const;

    bool getHas2() const;

    bool getIsComplete() const;

    float getMaxDistance() const;

    float getWeight1() const;

    float getWeight2() const;
};


// Метод создания структуры коррекции битвых пикселей изображения
public:
std::vector<DetectorCalibration::InterpolationPixel*> FindBadPixelInterpolations(int index, int imageWidth, int imageHeight, ISet<int> *badPixelSet);

// Внутренний метод 
private:
bool AddInterpolationLines(ICollection<DetectorCalibration::InterpolationPixel*> *interpolationPixels, InterpolationLine *a, InterpolationLine *b);
```

Вот исполнительный (**esemples.cpp**):

```
#include "esemples.h"

?????? (int index, int imageWidth, int imageHeight, ISet<int> *badPixelSet)
{
    auto interpolationPixels = std::vector<DetectorCalibration::InterpolationPixel*>();
    auto x = index % imageWidth;
    auto y = index / imageWidth;

    // Крест для поиска усреднения лево-право-верх-низ
    auto leftRight = new InterpolationLine(badPixelSet, index, x, imageWidth - x - 1, 1);
    auto topBottom = new InterpolationLine(badPixelSet, index, y, imageHeight - y - 1, imageWidth);

    if (!AddInterpolationLines(interpolationPixels, leftRight, topBottom))
    {
        // Диагональный крест для усреднения
        auto diag1 = new InterpolationLine(badPixelSet, index, std::min(x, y), std::min(imageWidth - x - 1, imageHeight - y - 1), imageWidth + 1);
        auto diag2 = new InterpolationLine(badPixelSet, index, std::min(imageWidth - x - 1, y), std::min(x, imageHeight - y - 1), imageWidth - 1);

        if (!AddInterpolationLines(interpolationPixels, diag1, diag2))
        {
            //  Берем хоть какие-то точки из креста лево-право-верх-низ
            auto weight = 1.0f / ((leftRight->getHas1() ? 1.0f : 0.0f) + (leftRight->getHas2() ? 1.0f : 0.0f) + (topBottom->getHas1() ? 1.0f : 0.0f) + (topBottom->getHas2() ? 1.0f : 0.0f));
            if (leftRight->getHas1())
            {
                DetectorCalibration::InterpolationPixel *tempVar = new DetectorCalibration::InterpolationPixel();
                tempVar->Index = leftRight->PixelIndex1;
                tempVar->Weight = weight;
                interpolationPixels.push_back(tempVar);
            }
            if (leftRight->getHas2())
            {
                DetectorCalibration::InterpolationPixel *tempVar2 = new DetectorCalibration::InterpolationPixel();
                tempVar2->Index = leftRight->PixelIndex2;
                tempVar2->Weight = weight;
                interpolationPixels.push_back(tempVar2);
                        }
            if (topBottom->getHas1())
            {
                DetectorCalibration::InterpolationPixel *tempVar3 = new DetectorCalibration::InterpolationPixel();
                tempVar3->Index = topBottom->PixelIndex1;
                tempVar3->Weight = weight;
                interpolationPixels.push_back(tempVar3);
            }
            if (topBottom->getHas2())
            {
                DetectorCalibration::InterpolationPixel *tempVar4 = new DetectorCalibration::InterpolationPixel();
                tempVar4->Index = topBottom->PixelIndex2;
                tempVar4->Weight = weight;
                interpolationPixels.push_back(tempVar4);
            }
        }
    }
    return interpolationPixels.ToArray();
}

InterpolationLine::InterpolationLine(ISet<int> *badPixelIndexes, int badPixelIndex, int maxDistance1, int maxDistance2, int step)
{
    maxDistance1 = std::min(MAX_DISTANCE, maxDistance1);
    maxDistance2 = std::min(MAX_DISTANCE, maxDistance2);

    auto index = badPixelIndex;
    for (auto distance = 1; distance <= maxDistance1; distance++)
    {
        index -= step;
        if (!badPixelIndexes->Contains(index))
        {
            PixelIndex1 = index;
            Distance1 = distance;
            break;
        }
    }

    index = badPixelIndex;
    for (auto distance = 1; distance <= maxDistance2; distance++)
    {
        index += step;
        if (!badPixelIndexes->Contains(index))
        {
            PixelIndex2 = index;
            Distance2 = distance;
            break;
        }
    }
}

bool InterpolationLine::getHas1() const
{
    return isfinite(Distance1);
}

bool InterpolationLine::getHas2() const
{
    return isfinite(Distance2);
}

bool InterpolationLine::getIsComplete() const
{
    return getHas1() && getHas2();
}

float InterpolationLine::getMaxDistance() const
{
    return std::max(Distance1, Distance2);
}

float InterpolationLine::getWeight1() const
{
    return 1.0f / (1.0f + Distance1 / Distance2);
}

float InterpolationLine::getWeight2() const
{
    return 1.0f / (1.0f + Distance2 / Distance1);
}

?????? ( *interpolationPixels, InterpolationLine *a, InterpolationLine *b)
{
    if (a->getIsComplete() && b->getIsComplete() && std::abs(a->getMaxDistance() - b->getMaxDistance()) < DISTANCE_DIFFERENCE_THRESHOLD)
    {
        // Усреднение крестом
        DetectorCalibration::InterpolationPixel *tempVar = new DetectorCalibration::InterpolationPixel();
        tempVar->Index = a->PixelIndex1;
        tempVar->Weight = 0.5f * a->getWeight1();
        interpolationPixels->Add(tempVar);
        DetectorCalibration::InterpolationPixel *tempVar2 = new DetectorCalibration::InterpolationPixel();
        tempVar2->Index = a->PixelIndex2;
        tempVar2->Weight = 0.5f * a->getWeight2();
        interpolationPixels->Add(tempVar2);
        DetectorCalibration::InterpolationPixel *tempVar3 = new DetectorCalibration::InterpolationPixel();
        tempVar3->Index = b->PixelIndex1;
        tempVar3->Weight = 0.5f * b->getWeight1();
        interpolationPixels->Add(tempVar3);
        DetectorCalibration::InterpolationPixel *tempVar4 = new DetectorCalibration::InterpolationPixel();
        tempVar4->Index = b->PixelIndex2;
        tempVar4->Weight = 0.5f * b->getWeight2();
        interpolationPixels->Add(tempVar4);
    }
    else if (a->getIsComplete() && (!b->getIsComplete() || a->getMaxDistance() < b->getMaxDistance()))
    {
        // Усреднение по одному направлению
        DetectorCalibration::InterpolationPixel *tempVar5 = new DetectorCalibration::InterpolationPixel();
        tempVar5->Index = a->PixelIndex1;
        tempVar5->Weight = a->getWeight1();
        interpolationPixels->Add(tempVar5);
        DetectorCalibration::InterpolationPixel *tempVar6 = new DetectorCalibration::InterpolationPixel();
        tempVar6->Index = a->PixelIndex2;
        tempVar6->Weight = a->getWeight2();
        interpolationPixels->Add(tempVar6);
    }
    else if (b->getIsComplete() && (!a->getIsComplete() || b->getMaxDistance() < a->getMaxDistance()))
    {
        // Усреднение по другому направлению
        DetectorCalibration::InterpolationPixel *tempVar7 = new DetectorCalibration::InterpolationPixel();
        tempVar7->Index = b->PixelIndex1;
        tempVar7->Weight = b->getWeight1();
        interpolationPixels->Add(tempVar7);
        DetectorCalibration::InterpolationPixel *tempVar8 = new DetectorCalibration::InterpolationPixel();
        tempVar8->Index = b->PixelIndex2;
        tempVar8->Weight = b->getWeight2();
        interpolationPixels->Add(tempVar8);
    }

    return interpolationPixels->Count > 0;
}
```

Проблемма у меня как правельно перевести в C++ методы, а также что сделать с созданными переменными `tempVar0 ... tempVar8` стоит ли пользоваться очисткой памяти ? и как ей пользоваться :3
вот на си шарп :

```
public DetectorCalibration.InterpolationPixel[] FindBadPixelInterpolations(int index, int imageWidth, int imageHeight, ISet<int> badPixelSet)  

private bool AddInterpolationLines(ICollection<DetectorCalibration.InterpolationPixel> interpolationPixels, InterpolationLine a, InterpolationLine b)
```

А как он должен выглядеть на си ++ я не совсем понимаю ;_;

```
?????? (int index, int imageWidth, int imageHeight, ISet<int> *badPixelSet)

?????? (*interpolationPixels, InterpolationLine *a, InterpolationLine *b)
```

Comment: `стоит ли пользоваться очисткой памяти` - сборщик мусора вы имели ввиду? Ааа, так его в C++ нет...